# Rbuildignore and Excluding Directories

Tags: r, package

I am interested in excluding two directories `inst\docs` and `inst\examples` while building and installing the package. I know that an easy way out is just to move `docs` and `examples` to the root directory and they won't get installed. However, I want to keep them in `inst` for other reasons.

I tried adding the following lines to `.Rbuildignore`

```
inst/docs
inst/examples
```

I use RStudio v 0.97 and `devtools` to build and install the package from source. However, when I do that, I still see that `inst\docs` and `inst\examples` get installed. I tried different regexes, but nothing seemed to work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue.  When using `install` in devtools the folders are ignored.  When building and install from the command line the folders are ignored.  But when using the 'Build & Reload' button in RStudio the folders get installed.  Seems like an RStudio problem

Comment: You are right. I used `devtools:install` and it worked perfectly. I am going to leave this question on here in case someone else has the same issue.

Comment: How do I see the .Rbuildignore folder? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: `.Rbuildignore` should be a text file in the package root directory; you will need to create this manually (perhaps using `usethis::use_build_ignore`) if it doesn't already exist

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with RStudio.  Using `install` from the devtools package seems to cause the folders to be ignored.  Building and installing directly from the command line also seems to cause the folders to be ignored.  The 'Build & Reload' button in RStudio, however, seems to not take into account the .Rbuildignore for those folders.

Comment: Posted [issue](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/3771-build-and-reload-package-does-not-respect-rbuildignore?unresolve=true) with RStudio

Comment: @Ramnath any reply to the above filed issue? The link no longer works and still experiencing RStudio ignoring `.Rbuildignore`

Comment: @DanielKrizian I think you should file the issue with devtools or rstudio if it is not resolved as yet.

Comment: Same [issue](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200654836-Build-and-Reload-Package-does-not-respect-Rbuildignore), but updated link.

Answer (score 35):

You can do

```
usethis::use_build_ignore(c("yourfolder1", "yourfolder2", "yourfile"))
```

Comment: updating, two years later: `use_build_ignore()` is now part of `usethis` and the `devtools` fxn is deprecated, so now instead do `usethis::use_build_ignore(c("yourfolder1", "yourfolder2", "yourfile"))`

Answer (score 5):

I find that I obtain the most consistent behaviour when treating each line of the `.Rbuildignore` file as a regular expression.
In your case I would manually create a text file in the root directory of the project named `.Rbuildignore` with the contents

```
^inst/docs
^inst/examples
```

The expression `^inst/docs` matches any file or folder that begins with (`^`) the string `inst/docs`.  `usethis::use_build_ignore()` adds a trailing `$` to each expression, which I have found can cause files within these folders not to be captured by the pattern (and thus not being ignored).

Answer (score 4):

Just to update, as of the latest versions, `devtools::use_build_ignore` has been moved to:

```
usethis::use_build_ignore(c("yourfolder1", "yourfolder2", "yourfile"))
```

Answer (score 3):

An old post but it still seems to be an issue when building binary packages. The following hack seems to work though (i.e., build source package and then build binary from that source package).

```
f <- devtools::build("mypackage")
system(paste0("R CMD INSTALL --build ", f))
```