# The correct use of devtools and/or RStudio with respect to .Rbuildignore

Tags: r, build, rstudio, devtools

I'd like to exclude the following ressources when building an R package via `.Rbuildignore`:

```
^.*\.Rproj$
^\.Rproj\.user$
inst/examples
inst/prof
man-roxygen
tests
```

But I'm confused as sometimes it seems to work and sometimes it doesn't.

I'm guessing that it has to do whether I'm using `devtools::build()`, `devtools::install()` or whatever exactly happens when hitting `SHFT + CTRL + B` (or *Build >> Build and Reload*) in RStudio.

The only relevant ressources I could find were [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182634/rbuildignore-and-excluding-directories) leading to [this issue](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200654836-Build-and-Reload-Package-does-not-respect-Rbuildignore), but I'm still not fully getting it.

This is what I tried:

1. *Load all* followed by *Build and Reload* via RStudio shortcuts:

   This is what I see when calling `list.files(file.path(R.home("library"), "mypackage"))`:

   ```
   [1] "DESCRIPTION" "examples"    "help"        "html"       
   [5] "INDEX"       "Meta"        "NAMESPACE"   "prof"       
   [9] "R"
   ```
2. *Load all* followed by *Build and Reload* followed by `devtools::install()`:

   This is what I see when calling `list.files(file.path(R.home("library"), "mypackage"))`:

   ```
    [1] "DESCRIPTION" "examples"    "help"        "html"       
    [5] "INDEX"       "Meta"        "NAMESPACE"   "prof"       
    [9] "R"           "tests"
   ```
3. `devtools::load_all()` followed by `devtools::build()` followed by `devtools::install()`:

   This is what I see when calling `list.files(file.path(R.home("library"), "mypackage"))`:

   ```
    [1] "DESCRIPTION" "examples"    "help"        "html"       
    [5] "INDEX"       "Meta"        "NAMESPACE"   "prof"       
    [9] "R"           "tests"
   ```

   Uncompressing the `.tar.gz` file and inspecting the directory content:

   ```
    [1] "DESCRIPTION" "man"          "NAMESPACE"  "R"
   ```
4. `devtools::load_all()` followed by `devtools::build(binary=TRUE)` followed by `devtools::install()`:

   ```
   [1] "DESCRIPTION" "examples"    "help"        "html"       
   [5] "INDEX"       "Meta"        "NAMESPACE"   "prof"       
   [9] "R"           "tests"
   ```

   Uncompressing the `.zip` file and inspecting the directory content:

   ```
   [1] "DESCRIPTION" "examples"    "help"        "html"       
   [5] "INDEX"       "MD5"         "Meta"        "NAMESPACE"  
   [9] "prof"        "R"
   ```

Looking at this also gives me reason to believe that I'm still not fully understanding the differences between `devtools::build()`, `devtools::install()` and `install.packages()` after the package has been built ;-)

Session Info:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] compiler  stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[6] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] mypackage_0.1.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] devtools_1.5    digest_0.6.4    evaluate_0.5.5 
 [4] httr_0.4        memoise_0.2.1   packrat_0.4.0.5
 [7] parallel_3.1.1  RCurl_1.95-4.3  stringr_0.6.2  
[10] tools_3.1.1     whisker_0.3-2
```

I'm using RStudio `0.98.978`

Comment: Have you tried to add to the `.Rbuildignore` file using regular expressions? `devtools::use_build_ignore("your_file")`

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200654836-Build-and-Reload-Package-does-not-respect-Rbuildignore

Answer (score 9):

The thing that works for me is to use `devtools::build` to make a source package, then `install.packages`.

```
devtools::build() %>% 
  install.packages(repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Using `devtools::build(binary = TRUE)` does not work, since it calls `R CMD INSTALL` rather than `R CMD build`, which ignores `.Rbuildignore` files.  Likewise, RStudio's "Build & Reload" button uses `R CMD INSTALL`.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering a similar problem when using `devtools::check_win_devel()` and `devtools::release()`.

For consistent behaviour, I have found that it helps to use regular expressions for all entries in `.Rbuildignore`.  This file would then become:

```
^.*\.Rproj$
^\.Rproj\.user$
^inst/examples
^inst/prof
^man\-roxygen
^tests
```

The directories are then ignored.