# devtools::load_all() does not respect scripts in .Rbuildignore

Tags: r, devtools

I am building an R package using `devtools`, but find that `load_all()` runs functions even when they are included in `.Rbuildignore` via `use_build_ignore()`. I've created a minimal package at https://github.com/adsteen/loadallfail/tree/master/R to illustrate the problem.

I created this package using `devtools::create("loadallfail")`. Then added a single file, `R/syntax_error.R`, with the following contents:

```
syntax_error <- function{
```

Next I opened the package project in RStudio and ran `devtools::use_build_ignore("syntax_error")`

When I run `load_all()` I get the following error:

```
Loading loadallfail
Error in parse(text = lines, n = -1, srcfile = srcfile) : 
  /Users/andrewsteen/Documents/Rpkgs/loadallfail/R/syntax_error.R:1:26: unexpected '{'
1: syntax_error <- function {
```

I would expect that the package would load successfully because anything matching the pattern in `.Rbuildignore` would not load and therefore not cause problems. What am I misunderstanding?

**Note**: a similar question is posted at [Rbuildignore and Excluding Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182634/rbuildignore-and-excluding-directories), but in that question the problem seemed to be an RStudio bug. I am using RStudio, but am calling all the `devtools` functions via the RStudio console (and in any case I can verify that `.Rbuildignore` looks like I think it should.)

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no provision in devtools to use .Rbuildignore for anything except *building* packages. Diving down the stack from `load_all()`, `devtools:::find_code()` seems to be what selects what to load and doesn't reference .Rbuildignore at all. I also searched the devtools repo for references to .Rbuildignore, none of the hits are in relevant functions.

Comment: That's kind of an odd decision, isn't it? I'm new to R package development, but I thought a.) most packages have some files that shouldn't be loaded, and b.) the point of `load_all()` is to quickly simulate building the package. So does `load_all()` typically fail during package development? I must be misunderstanding something about normal package development workflow.

Comment: `load_all()` is deliberately different than building the package.  For instance, it makes all internal functions available, not just exported ones.  I think its not so much meant to simulate building but just make everything available during development.  `.Rbuildignore` is more about keeping out extras  (like Travis files) that CRAN doesn't like.  I think a better workflow might be to put fragments in `inst/` and move them to `R/` when they are loadable.