# How to drop PackRat folder while submitting on CRAN

Tags: r, rstudio, cran, packrat

I have built a package in Rstudio on MAC OS and to better manage dependencies, I was using PackRat tool. Right now, my package passed all the tests, checks, and is getting built successfully. I have uploaded it on GitHub as well, but I saw that the packRat folder also got uploaded, which I think is not needed. 
And I have certainly never seen the packRat folder in any packages on CRAN.

How to get rid of the packRat folder altogether or how to hide it from getting into the source of the package that I will submit on CRAN?

My understanding is that to avoid putting packrat folder on Github, we can go Rstudio>tools>project options>packrat and check on the option 'git ignore packrat library and sources'.

But I cant figure what happens or should happen to Packrat folder while submitting to CRAN.

Any help, please?
Thank you..

Comment: Related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182634/rbuildignore-and-excluding-directories/

Answer (score 3):

You can add a file .Rbuildignore in the main directory if your package, and add the packRat folder to it.

So create a text file named `.Rbuildignore` (literally) and add the following line in it.

```
^packrat/
```

That should do it.

Note that RStudio does this automatically in a package project when you use packrat with it.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer @Joris I can see the text file is already present and the line is already added. Will this be enough to not include the Packrat folder in the source files that I will be submitting to CRAN? Thanks again.

Comment: @Usernow It excludes them in the source package I built on a very small test package, and that's the general way to exclude entire folders. You can always check by inspecting the .tar.gz file (using eg 7zip if you're on Windows) to see whether or not all the packrat info is stored or not. On a sidenote, I don't really see an advantage of using packrat for a package you want to upload on CRAN...